# MVC Generic Repository/Unit of Work pattern - Extending a repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Say I have the following implementation:

```
//Generic repository.
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class {
   void Insert(T entity);
   void Delete(int id);
   void SaveChanges();
   //..more generic functions
}

//Repository implementation.
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class {
   private MyDbContext context;
   protected DbSet<T> dbSet;

   public EFRepository(): this(new MyDbContext()){}

   public EFRepository(MyDbContext context)
   {
      this.context = context;
      dbSet = context.Set<T>();
   }

   public void Insert(T entity)
   {
      dbSet.Add(entity);
   }

   public void Delete(int id)
   {
      dbSet.Remove(dbSet.Find(id));
   }

   public void SaveChanges()
   {
      context.SaveChanges();
   }
   //...more generic implementations
}

//Unit of Work Interface
public interface IUnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
   IRepository<EntityA> ARepository { get; }
   IRepository<EntityB> BRepository { get; }
   //...more stuff
}

//Unit of Work Implementation
public class EFUnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
   private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

   private IRepository<EntityA> aRepository;
   private IRepository<EntityB> bRepository;

   public IRepository<EntityA> ARepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.aRepository == null)
               this.aRepository = new EFRepository<EntityA>(context);

            return this.aRepository;
      }

   }

   public IRepository<EntityB> BRepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.bRepository == null)
               this.bRepository = new EFRepository<EntityB>(context);

            return this.bRepository;
      }

   }

   //...more stuff
}
```

And finally, I have the following bindings in my resolver:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EFRepository<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).To(typeof(EFUnitOfWork));
```

Now, my question is... how would I go about extending the repository for EntityA so that it has more operations than just the generic ones?

I'll post what I have so far in a few...

EDIT: Here's what I have so far:

```
//New interface.
public class IEntityARepository : IRepository<EntityA>
{
   void DoSomethingSpecificToEntityA();
}

//New implementation.
public class EFEntityARepository : EFRepository<EntityA>
{
   public EFEntityARepository(MyDbContext context) : base(context) {}
   //add additional methods for EntityA
   public void DoSomethingSpecificToEntityA()
   {

   }

}


//Modify Unit of Work Interface as follows.
//Unit of Work Interface
public interface IUnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
   IEntityARepository  ARepository { get; }
   IRepository<EntityB> BRepository { get; }
   //...more stuff
}

//Modify Unit of Work Implementation as follows.
public class EFUnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
   private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

   private IEntityARepository  aRepository;
   private IRepository<EntityB> bRepository;

   public IEntityARepository   ARepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.aRepository == null)
               this.aRepository = new EFEntityARepository<EntityA>(context);

            return this.aRepository;
      }

   }

   public IRepository<EntityB> BRepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.bRepository == null)
               this.bRepository = new EFRepository<EntityB>(context);

            return this.bRepository;
      }

   }

   //...more stuff
}
```

Add the following binding:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IEntityARepository)).To(typeof(EFEntityARepository));
```

However, I'm sure this is not correct. Or at least, not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you could just derrive from a specifically typed version of your generic class like this...

```
public class EFEntityARepository : EFRepository<EntityA>, IEntityARepository 
{
    //Add more opps
}
```

I think the unit of work needs to look like this:

```
   public IEntityARepository   ARepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.aRepository == null)
               this.aRepository = new EFEntityARepository(context);

            return this.aRepository;
      }

   }
```

Comment: Is that all? Won't I have to make changes to the Unit of Work as well?

Comment: See edits above, I think you just need to return an instance of the derived class.

Comment: If you see my edit of the original post, my new implementation has that already. But it appears I've added/modified more stuff than I needed to.

Comment: Yeah, if I do only what you've suggested, it seems to complain that it cannot find the definition for the new method in IRepository<EntityA>. Which means, I have to define an interface for IRepository<EntityA>... as I've already done in the original post, no?

Comment: Yes, I have made an edit so you would need to also have this interface.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I've got it working by adding and/or modifying my original code as follows:

```
//New interface for the extension of the repository.
//Is it possible to do this without defining this new interface? Doesn't seem like it.
public class IEntityARepository : IRepository<EntityA>
{
   void DoSomethingSpecificToEntityA();
}

//Add new class.
//It looks like you have to inherit from IEntityARepository as well.
public class EFEntityARepository : EFRepository<EntityA>, IEntityARepository
{

   public EFEntityARepository(MyDbContext context) : base(context) {}

   //add additional methods for EntityA
   public void DoSomethingSpecificToEntityA()
   {

   }

}


//Modify Unit of Work Interface as follows.
public interface IUnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
   IEntityARepository ARepository { get; }
   IRepository<EntityB> BRepository { get; }
   //...more stuff
}

//Modify Unit of Work Implementation as follows.
public class EFUnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
   private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

   private IEntityARepository aRepository;
   private IRepository<EntityB> bRepository;

   public IEntityARepository ARepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.aRepository == null)
               this.aRepository = new EFEntityARepository(context);

            return this.aRepository;
      }

   }

   public IRepository<EntityB> BRepository 
   {
      get
      {
            if (this.bRepository == null)
               this.bRepository = new EFRepository<EntityB>(context);

            return this.bRepository;
      }

   }

   //...more stuff
}
```

It works... but is it the best way to go about it?

Comment: This comment is really late to the party, but I followed your solution for the exact same problem I'm having and found that it works. I also think there may be a different way to go about it. Have you found a better implementation since this last post?